FIREBASE_AUTHCHECK_DEBUG ReferenceError: self is not defined
Im Running into an Error implementing Firebase Appcheck
Next.js Typescript
firebase.ts
const fbapp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);



if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
  // @ts-ignore
  self.FIREBASE_APPCHECK_DEBUG_TOKEN = true;
}

initializeAppCheck(fbapp, {
  provider: new ReCaptchaV3Provider(
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_RECAPCHA_PUBLIC_KEY as string
  ),
  isTokenAutoRefreshEnabled: true
})

Eventhough Firebase aknowledges the existence of FIREBASE_APPCHECK_DEBUG_TOKEN = true and logs a Token for me to pass to console.firebase.. im getting ⨯ ReferenceError: self is not defined
bash logs
jackr@Jacks-PC MINGW64 /d/dev/NoPlus-web/noplus-web (web-dev)
$ npm run dev:next

> noplus-web@0.1.0 dev:next
> next dev

   ▲ Next.js 14.1.4
   - Local:        http://localhost:3000
   - Environments: .env

 ✓ Ready in 7.9s
 ○ Compiling / ...
 ⨯ Failed to find font override values for font `Bungee Spice`
 ⨯ Failed to find font override values for font `Bungee Spice`
 ✓ Compiled / in 22.2s (4020 modules)
 ⨯ src\components\firebase.ts (22:2) @ self
 ⨯ ReferenceError: self is not defined
    at eval (./src/components/firebase.ts:27:5)
    at (ssr)/./src/components/firebase.ts (D:\dev\NoPlus-web\noplus-web\.next\server\app\page.js:557:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (D:\dev\NoPlus-web\noplus-web\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at eval (./src/components/presets/functions/welcomeUser.tsx:6:67)
    at (ssr)/./src/components/presets/functions/welcomeUser.tsx (D:\dev\NoPlus-web\noplus-web\.next\server\app\page.js:667:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (D:\dev\NoPlus-web\noplus-web\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at eval (./src/app/page.tsx:12:84)
    at (ssr)/./src/app/page.tsx (D:\dev\NoPlus-web\noplus-web\.next\server\app\page.js:440:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (D:\dev\NoPlus-web\noplus-web\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
  20 | if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
  21 |   // @ts-ignore
> 22 |   self.FIREBASE_APPCHECK_DEBUG_TOKEN = true;
     |  ^
  23 | }
  24 |
  25 | initializeAppCheck(fbapp, {
 ✓ Compiled in 2.5s (1850 modules)
 ✓ Compiled in 552ms (1836 modules)

Im having issues Posting the issue so please read the rest on github
text

On Stack Overflow, do not require the reader to use links to external information. Everything should be in the question itself so future readers always have immediate access to it. If you have code, copy and paste it into the question so it's easy to read, copy, and search.

try this
const fbapp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
  // @ts-ignore
  globalThis.FIREBASE_APPCHECK_DEBUG_TOKEN = true;
}

initializeAppCheck(fbapp, {
  provider: new ReCaptchaV3Provider(
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_RECAPCHA_PUBLIC_KEY as string
  ),
  isTokenAutoRefreshEnabled: true
})

you might want to see what-is-globalthis-in-javascript-what-will-be-the-ideal-use-case-for-this
